# How to calculate the integral of exponential functions?

Tags: integration, exponential-function

Having an integral like $\int_{2}^{10}{\frac{x}{\ln x}}dx$

How does this function turns to an exponential integral of the form:

$ \operatorname{Ei}(x)=-\int_{-x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}t\,dt.\,$

For instance how did  $\int_{2}^{10}{\frac{x}{\ln x}}dx$ became $\text{Ei}\left(2\ln \left(10\right)\right)-\text{Ei}\left(2\ln \left(2\right)\right)$? and how to get a value from $\text{Ei}\left(2\ln \left(10\right)\right)-\text{Ei}\left(2\ln \left(2\right)\right)$?

Is it possible to show in steps how to integrate such function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, let $x=e^t$ to make
$$\int{\frac{x}{\ln x}}\,dx=\int \frac {e^{2t}}t\,dt=\int \frac {e^{u}}u\,du=\text{Ei}(u)$$

Concerning the evaluation of it, you can use the expansion
$$\text{Ei}(u)=\gamma+\log (u)
   +\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {u^n}{n \, n!}$$ and truncate when you consider that you have a sufficient accuracy.

For your case, truncating to $p$ terms, we should have as result
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \text{result} \\
 5 & 22.608730259124323872 \\
 10 & 27.090361747387535417 \\
 15 & 27.158393354747179833 \\
 20 & 27.158556390565134126 \\
 25 & 27.158556489020573262 \\
 30 & 27.158556489040577392
\end{array}
\right)$$

For large values of $u$, use the asymptotics
$$\text{Ei}(u)\sim\frac{e^u}u \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {n!}{u^n}$$ For $u=100$, you should get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{result} \\
 0 & 2.68811714181614\times 10^{41} \\
 1 & 2.71499831323430\times 10^{41} \\
 2 & 2.71553593666266\times 10^{41} \\
 3 & 2.71555206536551\times 10^{41} \\
 4 & 2.71555271051362\times 10^{41} \\
 5 & 2.71555274277103\times 10^{41} \\
 6 & 2.71555274470648\times 10^{41} \\
 7 & 2.71555274484196\times 10^{41} \\
 8 & 2.71555274485279\times 10^{41} \\
 9 & 2.71555274485377\times 10^{41} \\
 10 & 2.71555274485387\times 10^{41}
\end{array}
\right)$$